# Using a constructor function in the same way a class extends works?

Tags: javascript

I have been using Classes for ease of understand prototypes.  It makes logical sense that extending a class lets you inherit from that base class.  How would I do the below code using function constructors though? :

```
class Person {
     constructor(name,age,speciality="Not Specified") {
         this.name = name; 
         this.age = age;
         this.speciality = speciality;
     }
     sayName() {
        return this.name;
     }

}

class Athlete extends Person {

      constructor(name, age, speciality) {
          super(name,age)
          this.speciality = speciality
      }
      getSport() {
          return "I play " + this.speciality;
      }

}

let john = new Person('john', 44)

let jim = new Athlete('jim', 54, 'basketball');
```

I know I would have:

```
function Person(name,age,speciality="Not Specified") {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.speciality = speciality;
}
```

I assume I would have `sayName()` as a prototype rather than a property inside Person like:

```
   Person.prototype.sayName = function() {
        return this.name;
   }
```

but then how would I have an Athlete constructor that inherits these like I can do with extending a class?

Answer (score 0):

With the class, the prototype chain for an Athlete is:

```
instance <- Athlete.prototype <- Person.prototype
```

With `Function`s, the internal prototype of instances is the `.prototype` property on the function used to construct it. Just like with classes, the internal prototype of `new Foo()` will be `Foo.prototype`. So, to extend it manually, you need to set the `.prototype` property to an object that inherits from `Person.prototype`:

```js
function Person(name, age, speciality = "Not Specified") {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.speciality = speciality;
}
Person.prototype.sayName = function() {
  return this.name;
}

function Athlete(name, age, speciality) {
  Person.call(this, name, age, speciality);
  this.speciality = speciality;
}

Athlete.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Athlete.prototype.getSport = function() {
  return "I play " + this.speciality;
};



let jim = new Athlete('jim', 54, 'basketball');
console.log(jim.sayName());
console.log(jim.getSport());
```